# Allow insecure networks for Delphi Edge Browser component

Tags: delphi, microsoft-edge, webview2

I am using Edge browser component of Delphi 11.1 in order to automate a navigation process. The problem is that at the start of the navigation process I get the Message "Your connection isn't private" & the whole process stops until I press the button "Advanced" & the button "Continue to 1xx.xx.xx.xx (unsafe)"!

I have to mention that when I navigate to this intranet site via Windows Edge Browser I do not get that Message since I have uploaded the certificate of this site & I have also added it to the exceptions of Edge browser.

I think that I have to set it somehow the "InsecurePrivateNetworkRequestsAllowed" property to true but I cannot find the way or to upload somehow the certificate to Delphi's Edge browser component.

Any Ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insecure connection warning can be bypassed by clicking on the Proceed link.

Below there is a code sample:

```
procedure TForm1.EdgeBrowserNavigationCompleted(Sender: TCustomEdgeBrowser;
  IsSuccess: Boolean; WebErrorStatus: TOleEnum);
resourcestring
  scProceed =
    'function run() { ' +
    '  var e = document.getElementById("proceed-link"); ' +
    '  if (e) e.click(); ' +
    '} run();';
begin
  if not IsSuccess and (WebErrorStatus = COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_ERROR_STATUS_CERTIFICATE_IS_INVALID) then
    EdgeBrowser.ExecuteScript(scProceed);
end;
```

Another way is to control the WebView2 behaviour using [CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions.AdditionalBrowserArguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environmentoptions.additionalbrowserarguments). Some of arguments are documented [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Currently, Delphi 11.1 does not allow you to manage them using some component/interface, but such options could be set using `WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS` environement varialble before WebView initialization:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetEnvironmentVariable('WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS',
    '--ignore-certificate-errors');
  EdgeBrowser.CreateWebView;
end;
```

Note, this option could be removed in future because of security concerns and sporadic debates on it.

Comment: Why not simply executing `document.getElementById("proceed-link").click()`? Must it be a function? The resourcestring has no linebreaks anyway...

Comment: @AmigoJack, Because you have to check yet for valid element before invoking click(), it may not exists, and it may throw a JS error or needs to be handled accordingly. JavaScript code runs in global context. A function solves variable collisions. In case if "e" is already defined earlier running direct complex code may break other things. JS functions make code look more organized, especially when you have multiple scripts for automation.

Comment: Not handling a potential error does no damage in this case: either one succeeds to click it or not - there's no gain in that one check. The JS code will not look organized in the EXE anymore, because it has only spaces, but no linebreaks - the linebreaks are only in the Pascal code. If that's the argument I would have added `#$d#$a` to every literal.

Comment: Normally you should handle such errors, because the whole automation process hangs in an ideterminate state. Usually it is done by posting a web message to host application by notifying that something goes wrong. Yes, JS code is formatted in pascal source. You can disable/change some lines by commenting individual lines of code. I do not need them  formatted on WebView side nor completelly related to eol terminators.